# Open Navigation Drawer by button

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I tried to called navigation drawer from my activity, but nothing happened.Should I used ActionBarDrawerToggle?

```
  public class SettingsDrawer {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<SettingsDrawerItem> items;
        ListView listView;
        ImageView logo;
         DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        public  SettingsDrawer(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;   
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_drawer_layout, null);
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
            logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            DrawListAdapter adapter = new DrawListAdapter(mContext, items);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
```

And in my activity

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

Button settingsDrawerButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.settingsDrawer);
        settingsDrawerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG,"settings drawer click!");
                SettingsDrawer s = new SettingsDrawer(Activity.this);

            }
        });
}
```

UPDATE: XML I tried to set up like that: mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerPane) but Ive got classCastException as well. I thought it was quite understable because the DrawerLayout cannot casts to RelativeLayout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/logoBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/settingsList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logoBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: add this line                                                 mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(listView);

Answer (score 1):

Find the drawer layout like this:

```
  myDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.yourdrawer);
```

The variable `myDrawerLayout` should be field in your activity:

```
DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
```

Then its Better to make a method like this in your activity:

```
public void openDrawer(){
myDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLayout);
```

}

Then easily call this method whever you want to close the drawer ;)

Comment: yup but i want to setup my Drawer content in specyfic class and then called it from the couple activity to not reapeating code in each activity

Comment: You cant open the drawer from another class cuz it belongs to this activity. You can make this method public static though. Btw This is actually not a good practice but all that you can do.

Comment: I know that so i wanted to setup my drawer each time when I go to diffrent activities, thats why I implement SettingsDrawer in separate class. The issue is, that i cannot called the drawer from my activity class

Comment: Can you put the code of that other class yout talking about ?

Comment: I think we have a little misunderstood. The SettingsDrawer setting all conent that drawer have. In several activities I setting up my drawer by call SettingsDrawer s = new SettingsDrawer (activityName.this)

Answer (score 0):

mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(listView);

Comment: This throw me classCastException, although i don't think its a good idea, because In my DrawerLayou Ive got couple items not only a list.

Comment: can you post your XML part?

Comment: please try like this myDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerPane);

Comment: private void openAndColseDrawerList() {
        if (myDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerPane);
        } else
            myDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerPane);
    } this is worked for me no exceptions.!

Answer (score 0):

```
the below code is my xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="mActivity">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/mDrawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mDrawerMainLayout"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/mListView"
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </RelativeLayout> `from that I fixed  private void` 

openAndColseDrawerList() {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerMainLayout);
        } else
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerMainLayout);
    }
```

Comment: Okey I guess I know what is the problem. The Activity have a diffrent layout xml than the setting_drawer_layout. When I open the Drawer it trigger in diffrent view and nothing happened. Do you have any idea how to made it to trigger in activity view?

Comment: i think you better to use SettingsDrawer extend fragment  and implement within your Acivity